# Converting raster to spatial points without loss of information in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I am currently trying to convert a rasterlayer into a spatial points object so that I can use spTransform to reproject into a new CRS. I tried to do this using the "as()" function, but the output (called Spat_points_NSW) has a different number of features (122244) compared to the number of cells (203082) in the rasterlayer object (called ndvi_median) that was used as an input.

```
> ndvi_median
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1122, 181, 203082  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.09978817, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 140.9993, 159.0609, -37.50702, -28.15702  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs 
source     : C:/Users/U/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWGYBpT/raster/r_tmp_2021-05-16_201533_15536_51645.grd 
names      : layer 
values     : -1966, 9009.5  (min, max)
> Spat_points_NSW<-as(ndvi_median,"SpatialPoints")
> Spat_points_NSW
class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 122244 
extent      : 141.0492, 153.6225, -37.50285, -28.16119  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs
```

I also note that the extent has changed during this conversion (although slightly).
So my current understanding is that for some reason, 203082-122244=80838 cells worth of data is being lost in this conversion.

How can I prevent this dataloss?

Comment: Note some people have commented on this not being a good way to project rasters. If you arent sure, try writing a new question asking about what you are trying to achieve with this process (rather than how to do it). There are applications for transforming rasters as grids of points but we can't be sure if yours is one unless you ask that new question.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you for your suggestion! Your advice makes sense to me, and I have followed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see. First make a 5x4 raster:

```
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
> r = raster(matrix(1:20,5,4))
> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 5, 4, 20  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.25, 0.2  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 20  (min, max)
```

And try `as(r, "SpatialPoints")`:

```
> as(r,"SpatialPoints")
class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 20 
extent      : 0.125, 0.875, 0.1, 0.9  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : NA
```

and I get 20 points, as expected. Let's put an NA value in the raster:

```
> r[1,1]=NA
> as(r,"SpatialPoints")
class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 19 
extent      : 0.125, 0.875, 0.1, 0.9  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : NA
```

and I get 19 points ("features"). So that explains that.

The coercion method used by `as` there is this:

```
> getMethod("coerce",list("Raster","SpatialPoints"))
Method Definition:

function (from, to = "SpatialPoints", strict = TRUE) 
{
    SpatialPoints(rasterToPoints(from, spatial = FALSE)[, 1:2], 
        proj4string = .getCRS(from))
}
```

which you might also note is dropping all the raster *values*, so all you get is the points. It uses `rasterToPoints` and then drops everything but the coordinates. The code for `rasterToPoints` is almost what you want, but it always drops NA values. Instead we can convert to a data frame,
and then convert that to a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`:

```
> m = as.data.frame(r,xy=TRUE); coordinates(m)=~x+y
> m
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 20 
extent      : 0.125, 0.875, 0.1, 0.9  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : NA 
variables   : 1
names       : layer 
min values  :     2 
max values  :    20
```

which has 20 features and preserves the raster values and returns the NA:

```
> m$layer
 [1] NA  6 11 16  2  7 12 17  3  8 13 18  4  9 14 19  5 10 15 20
```

Now the extent is slightly smaller because the extent for a raster is to the outer edges of the cells, but the points are at the centre of the cells, so you'd expect the point data set extent to be half a cell-width off each edge:

```
> extent(r)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 0 
xmax       : 1 
ymin       : 0 
ymax       : 1 
> res(r)
[1] 0.25 0.20
```

which it is:

```
> extent(m)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 0.125 
xmax       : 0.875 
ymin       : 0.1 
ymax       : 0.9
```

any NA values in your original `as(r, "SpatialPoints")` that result in trimming an entire edge of NA cells off will reduce the extent even more.

Answer (score 3):

Converting to SpatialPoints drops the raster attribute information, I believe you are looking for SpatialPointsDataFrame. The most likely reason for the discrepancy in size is that NA values are dropped when converted to points. You can avoid this by converting to something like a SpatialPixelsDataFrame, which is the sp raster class. Now, that said, you do not need to convert to sp points to reproject. You can use the projectRaster in the raster package or, to speed things up convert the raster to a rast class so you can reproject using the terra package (the eventual replacement for raster). For raster data you want to be able to control the specific resolution and resampling method. This is especially important when projecting from geographic (lat/long) coordinates.